# Inner Join table based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Payment with 2 columns id and triptype. My requirement is such that if triptype is 1 then I should perform an inner join with table1, but if it's 2 then I should perform the join with table2. I have tried using `UNION` but I am unable to resolve this. What do I need to do?

Comment: Show us your current query!

Comment: Do the join which each two tables and then use select case for select the correct fields

Comment: Please show us the query that you have and what the error is. The union solution you proposed yourself should work fine. Make sure the columns in both parts of the union are present and in the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `UNION` working, you must ensure same column structure and type for all set

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, b.name FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON 
    a.type = 1 AND a.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT a.id, a.type, c.name FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table3 c ON 
    a.type = 2 AND a.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
SELECT A.ID, 
           CASE WHEN A.TRIPTYPE = 1 THEN B.[YOUR_COLUMN_TABLE_1]
                WHEN A.TRIPTYPE = 2 THEN C.[YOUR_COLUMN_TABLE_2]
           END
    FROM PAYMENT AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_1 AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 AS C ON A.ID = C.ID
```

Comment: Maybe is is right if TABLE_1 and TABLE_2 has the same IDs. But it is not sure. I think the LEFT JOIN is better (filter out when there is no record from TABLE_1 nor TABLE_2).

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
select t.id, 
       case t.triptype when 1 then t1.SomeColumn
                       when 2 then t2.SomeColumn end as SomeColumn
from table t
left join table1 t1 on t.id = t1.id
left join table2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Hmmm, and where is the comment? :)

Comment: I guess it should return empty row for inner join if no match. Or you add the where condition such as `WHERE ISNULL(t1.id, t2.id) IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @Eric, sure one can filter out those rows where match is not found in t1 nor in t2. But OP has not tell anything abount it.